# TabBar Issue in LandScapeMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I Created one Demo App For TabBar, in that i took one .xib and in that i added one UITabBar, and  i added two UITabBarItem. And When i am run the application in portrait mode it is working fine and design looks good. in portrait mode design look like below

[image]

But When i am rotating device to landscape that time image and title alignment changed, it is not showing proper, landscape mode image is look like below

[image]

Can you please suggest me solution for this. 
Note - I am not using TabBarController, only TabBar and TabBarItems

Comment: Did you set any custom offset for `title` in tabbar Item ?

Comment: Yes, i checked using it, but custom offset of title is not appropriate for all iOS Devices. i want to use this in both iPad and iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem, you want to add one method into your viewController.m file which have a TabBar.

1. If you application not supporting dark mode(i mean you disable dark mode) then you need to add this method

   ```
   -(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
           if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                  return [super traitCollection];
           }else{
                  return [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact];
           }
   }
   ```
2. If your application supporting dark mode then you need to add this method

   ```
   -(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
             return [super traitCollection];
        }else{
             UITraitCollection *superSizeClass = [super traitCollection];
             UITraitCollection *verticalSizeClass = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithVerticalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular];

             NSArray *combinedTraitArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: superSizeClass,verticalSizeClass, nil];

             UITraitCollection *combinedTraits = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraitsFromCollections: combinedTraitArray];
             return combinedTraits;
       }
   }
   ```

It will work for this issue. Thanks.